# sed find and replace not replacing values

Tags: json, bash, amazon-web-services, sed, terraform

I have entered a bash script which should replace some values within some terraform files so the user can input the IP address and the access/secret keys. But my script is having the following problems.

When the variables script is run, the sg.tf ip changes are not taken into effect and the provider file changes appear in the following way,

if the value 123 is added to the access key input it would appear in the file as

access_key = "123"EnterACCESSKEY"

The reason there is a * character is because the idea is the script should be able to run multiple times but give the same results so it shouldn't have to look for a specific value to replace as long as the surrounding string matches.

variables.sh script

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter Public IP without CIDR notation " IP
sed -i "s/cidr_blocks = [*]/cidr_blocks = [\"$IP\/32\"]/1" sg.tf
sed -i "s/cidr_blocks = [*]/cidr_blocks = [\"$IP\/32\"]/3" sg.tf

read -p "Enter AWS ACCESS KEY: " ACCESSKEY
sed -i "s/access_key = \"*\"/access_key = \"$ACCESSKEY\"/g" providers.tf

read -p "Enter AWS SECRET KEY: " SECRETKEY
sed -i "s/secret_key = "*"/secret_key = "$SECRETKEY"/g" providers.tf
```

sg.tf contents

```
   ingress {
        from_port = 22
        to_port = 22
        protocol = "TCP"
        cidr_blocks = ["EnterIP/32"]
        }
egress {
        from_port       = 0
        to_port         = 0
        protocol        = "-1"
        description = "Allow all ports outgoing"
        cidr_blocks     = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
        }
ingress {
        from_port = 80
        to_port = 80
        protocol = "TCP"
        cidr_blocks = ["EnterIP/32"]
        }
egress {
        from_port       = 0
        to_port         = 0
        protocol        = "-1"
        description = "Allow all ports outgoing"
        cidr_blocks     = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
        }
}
```

provider file

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = "EnterACCESSKEY"
  secret_key = "EnterSECRETKEY"
  region = "eu-west-1"
}
```

Comment: It seems like you don't understand how `*` works in regular expressions, you're using it like a wildcard pattern.

Comment: Don't use sed for this. Set variables that can be passed in properly by Terraform instead and/or rely on the AWS credential chain (env vars/credentials file/etc) instead.

Comment: I did try and find a way to input the credentials through terraform, but i could not find a way @ydaetskcoR

Comment: Did you read https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/index.html#authentication ?

Comment: okay i had a look and it can just export the keys into env variables which would replace sed, thanks. @ydaetskcoR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a regular expression, `*` is a quantifier for the pattern before it, it's not a wildcard by itself. So `"*"` means to match any number of `"` followed immediately by `"`, it doesn't mean `"` and `"` with anything in between them.

Also, `[` is a special operator, used to create a character set match, so you need to escape it to match it literally.

You forgot to escape the embedded quotes in the last `sed` command.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter Public IP without CIDR notation " IP
sed -i "s/cidr_blocks = \[.*\]/cidr_blocks = [\"$IP\/32\"]/1" sg.tf
sed -i "s/cidr_blocks = \[.*\]/cidr_blocks = [\"$IP\/32\"]/3" sg.tf

read -p "Enter AWS ACCESS KEY: " ACCESSKEY
sed -i "s/access_key = \".*\"/access_key = \"$ACCESSKEY\"/g" providers.tf

read -p "Enter AWS SECRET KEY: " SECRETKEY
sed -i "s/secret_key = \".*\"/secret_key = \"$SECRETKEY\"/g" providers.tf
```

Comment: Just following the suggests in the previous comments so my script ended up looking like this. Confirmed this works. Many thanks.

Comment: seems running the script now replaces all cidr blocks including the egress rules even thought it states replace the 1st and 3rd occurance in the sed commands. I do not suppose you can see why? THanks @Barmar

Comment: Which lines have more than one cidr block on them?

Comment: I am not following the question

Comment: The `/3` modifier means to only replace the third match on the line. But you don't have 3 matches on any line.

Comment: ah I misunderstood what /3 did then, I thought it would replace the 1st and 3rd find match not in the actual line itself.

Comment: You can put a range at the beginning, `1,3s/.../.../` means to do the replacement on lines 1-3 of the file.

Comment: @Barmar I understand that you're answering the question as it stands and don't have exposure to Terraform but this is an X Y problem. The OP is much better off understanding how to pass variables into Terraform properly rather than using sed.